# Nginx Rewrite that Parses jpg as php

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm converting from Apache to Nginx and I hit a tricky rewrite rule.  Here is a sample link:

```
/cats/Parameter_1/Parameter_2.jpg
```

I'm matching "Paramter_1" and "Parameter_2" then ignoring the ".jpg" file extension.  This worked just fine in Apache.

Here is the original Apache Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^cats/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]*) /includes/cats/fan/001.php?Parameter_1=$1&Parameter_2=$2 [L]
```

This is the non-working Nginx rewrite that I made:

```
rewrite ^/cats/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]*) /includes/cats/fan/001.php?Parameter_1=$1&Parameter_2=$2 last;
```

I have converted two other rewrites using this pattern.  What makes this different is that the link ends in ".jpg" and I think Nginx doesn't know to parse this as a php file.

Do any of you more experienced folks have an idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Not clear what's wrong. Show full nginx config and describe what's the problem is/

Comment: I was making a newbie mistake.  Anyone trying to parse a .jpg as a .php file e.g.  http://YourDomain.com/image.jpg shows a page generated via php instead of the image needs to use try_files.

try_files $uri $uri/ /includes/blog/001.php?gallery_folder1=$1&gallery_folder2=$2 ;